# How can we do feature selection on json data?

Tags: json, machine-learning, feature-selection

I have large dataset in json format from which I want to extract important attributes whcih captures the most variance. I want to extract these attributes to build a search engine on the dataset with these attributes being the hash key.

The main question being asked here is doing feature selection on a json data.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the data into a pandas DataFrame Object with the [pandas.read_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) function. You can use this DataFrame Object to gain insight into your data. For example:

```
data = pandas.load_json(json_file)
data.head() # Displays the top five rows
data.info() # Displays description of the data
```

Or you can use matplotlib on this DataFrame to plot a histogram for each numerical attribute

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data.hist(bins=50, figsize=(20,15))
```

If you are interested into correlation of attributes, you can use the pandas.scatter_matrix() function.

You have to manually pick the attributes that fit best to your task and this tools help you to understand the data and gain insight into it.